# Quick Java garbage collection question

Tags: java, collections, reference, garbage

I am writing an alarm app in Android, and I have the following:

```
ArrayList<PendingIntent> pendingIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

public PendingIntent setAlarm(long time) {
    ...other code.
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, num, intent, flags);
    return pi;
}
```

I am wondering if doing this below multiple times, is the original Pending Intent reference overridden each time?

```
pendingIntents.add(num, setAlarm(1000));
```

Answer (score 2):

### NO

Basically, you are temporarily assigning to the object reference to variable `pi`. The variable is overwritten, but the object is not. It safely gets added to your list for any future use.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thank you!

Comment: @thomas farrell, glad it helped. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered by clicking on the up-tick next to this answer. [See here how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not.

Each time you call `add` you insert an element after the specified index.

Perhaps you've meant to use [`set`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29).  That one replaces item at the `num` position and the old value becomes eligible for GC.

Comment: Nope.  I wanted to make sure that the objects created on the heap would all be separate objects with each object in my arraylist pointing to each individual object.  Thanks!